# How to make list of lists, where you take the square and cube of each even number?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I would like to make a list of lists after squaring and cubing each even number.

Below is my code i have thus far:

```
def sq_cube(numbers):
    ls1 = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i%2 == 0:
            ls1.append(i)
        else:
            pass

    ls2square = [x**2 for x in ls1]
    ls3cube = [x**3 for x in ls1]

    ls4all = list(ls2square +ls3cube)
return ls4all


RUN: sq_cube([1,2,3,4,6])
OUTPUT:[4, 16, 36, 8, 64, 216]

I would love my OUTPUT to be: [[4, 8], [16, 64], [36, 216]]
```

ls1: Here I sorted the list 1,2,3,4,6 into even numbers.

ls2square: Squared the even number in ls1.

ls3cube: Cubed the even numbers in ls1.

As you can see in my OUTPUT it gives both lists but it does not give each even
number its separate list where that even number was squared and cubed.

Comment: `+` concatenates two lists. To make a nested list, you have to actually make it in a loop or a list-comp

Comment: @WilliamMartens Python 2 reached end-of-life on Jan 1st 2020. You should link to python3 docs unless the question is explicitly about Python2 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: My god I didn't notice that!! thanks!  Gosh,  really - thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: `ls4all = list(zip(ls2square, ls3cube))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from `ls4all`. You code is

```
ls4all = list(ls2square +ls3cube)
```

variable `ls4all` does not contain the desired list of lists: `[[4, 8], [16, 64], [36, 216]]` since it's the concatenation of `ls2square` and `ls3cube`. We would rather like to have the list of pairs of elements in `ls2square` and `ls3cube`. To achieve that, you can create an iterator that outputs the pairs of elements of `ls2square` and `ls3cube`, for instance, using `zip` command.

`zip` command works like that:

```py
>>> list(zip([1,10], [2,20]))
[(1, 2), (10, 20)]
```

As you can see, it gathers together elements in `[1,10]` and `[2,20]`, making pairs.
So you can use `zip` this way:

```py
ls2square = [4, 16, 36]
ls3cube = [8, 64, 216]
ls4all = list([a,b] for a,b in zip(ls2square, ls3cube))
print(ls4all)
```

anyway, a shorter answer would be:

```py
>>> print([(k**2, k**3) for k in [1,2,3,4,6] if k % 2 == 0])
[(4, 8), (16, 64), (36, 216)]
```

UPDATE:
In case your integers have type `float`,  `k % 2` will raise the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: float modulo
```

So, if you want to round your float to the closest integer, just use `round` function like so:

```py
ls2square = [round(x)**2 for x in ls1]
ls3cube = [round(x)**3 for x in ls1]
```

Short answer above is now:

```py
>>> print([(round(k)**2, round(k)**3) for k in [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0] if round(k) % 2 == 0])
[(4, 8), (16, 64), (36, 216)]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: `if not k%2` looks really strange. For better readability, I'd write `if k%2 == 0`.

Comment: Not really, no! You replaced "here's your code" with "here's your code. Do this." _Explain_  what your code does. Why does "the problem come from `ls4all`? What is the problem? Why does OP's approach not work? Clearly, OP is a beginner, they'd find an answer that tells them how to avoid this mistake much more useful than an answer that tells them how to fix it just this once.

Comment: @Muffin I assume your values are integer values caster in float values like `2.0` or `14.0`.
To do this, just use `int()` function that cast your `float` type in `int` type.

Comment: @dallonsi ok kwl thanks, because I would like to test it on Integers and Float values. :)

Comment: @dallonsi Sorry I stated it incorrectly, if I would like to Round it to the nearest whole number how should it look, my bad. :)

Comment: @dallonsi do i just change int to round() ?

Comment: @dallonsi   iF use that code with round() then if i run this: sq_cube([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9]) then the Output should be: [[4, 8], [16, 64], [36, 216], [64, 512], [100, 1000]] but i do not get the correct answer it gives me: [(5, 11), (19, 85), (30, 166), (59, 457), (98, 970)].

Comment: @Muffin which code ? Your corrected answer or the "short answer" in my post ?

Comment: Ok I saw the problem I wrote `round(k**2), round(k**3)`, instead of `round(k)**2, round(k)**3` ;) I just updated my answer

Comment: @dallonsi yeah, I also changed it like that on my end and worked, Thanks for the help, you're a champion!

Answer (score 0):

since you want the squares and the cubes of the same number to be in the same list you could use this, since both lists(ls2square,ls3cube) have the same length instead of just adding them together you can add in seperate list the each corisponding elements that they have, element 0 in ls2square goes with element 0 of ls3cube and so on:

```
def sq_cube(numbers):
    ls1 = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i%2 == 0:
            ls1.append(i)
        else:
            pass

    ls2square = [x**2 for x in ls1]
    ls3cube = [x**3 for x in ls1]
    ls4all= [[ls2square[k],ls3cube[k]] for k in range(len(ls3cube))]
    return ls4all
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list
Round incoming list
loop for every number to check if even
then square and cube that number

```py
def sq_cube(numbers):
    new_string = []
    numbers = [round(num) for num in numbers]
    for W in numbers:
      if W % 2 ==0:
        new_string.append([W**2,W**3])
        
    return new_string
```